# How does Te3n justify its title?

Tags: analysis, title, te3n

In the movie Te3n, the child that is kidnapped is around six to eight years. Then how is the movie named teen? Is there any other logic for this title?

Comment: Maybe it refers to 3rd october when the incident took place i.e. the kidnapping of Angela

Comment: In the end, only 3 people know the truth, which is why the movie title is called Te3n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is you are confusing Te3n with teen (teenager).

But Te3n in the film title refers to तीन (Hindi word for number 3 and pronounced as teen/theen). Even the film has three major characters played by Amitabh Bachchan, Nawazuddin Siddiqui, and Vidya Balan. So the title refers to their conflict and journey.

Comment: And the "3" is pronounced "teen", right? That's what I saw on Twitter when Mark Kermode asked a similar question WRT this title.

Comment: @BCdotWEB yes, almost like that.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but it doesn't seem very convincing... I'd say Amitabh Bachchan had the major role and the other 2 were not as big. I don't think it justifies the title being TE3N. Maybe they just couldn't think of a better name...

Comment: @AkshayDamle It always happen, every actor doesn't get equal footage. But title do refer to those three.

Comment: Yeah I guess it does but it doesn't seem like a very good reason to keep that title. It's not as if they were some 3 heroes working together or anything. The story didn't even emphasize so much on the relationship between the individuals - it was quite fast paced and didn't really let that development happen. So why they would not choose a better title beats me.

Comment: @AkshayDamle yeah, reasonable point.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinoin...teen refers to 3 investigations... 
1. For Angela..by Nawaz
2. For Angela again..but now by Amithabh
And
3.For Ronnie ..by Vidya balan...

Just a thought

Comment: You've missed the point of the question - the OP was unaware of the Hindi word for three.